# JAVA :: Garbage characters encoding

Tags: java, unicode, character-encoding

I am getting garbled string ("à¤•à¤¿à¤¸à¤¾à¤¨à¥‹à¤‚ à¤•à¥‡ à¤²à¤) from web and I want to convert that into Hindi language in JAVA. I have tried below code but somehow its not working properly,

```
         s = new String(str.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
```

It shows few hindi characters but not all. It shows weird characters like � and ?.

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: What is `str`? Your garbled String from the web should come as bytes which you convert to a String with the correct encoding.

Comment: Have you tried other encodings? You could try them all in a loop to see which one seems right.

Comment: Garbage characters? Call `System.gc();` and then try again.

Comment: Hi Peter, I don't know how to check all encoding ? I am new to Java so not much idea. Can you please suggest something ?

Comment: I checked all encoding and does not look like anything is working correctly.

Answer (score 3):

> new String(str.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");

This is attempting to recover a string that has been incorrectly decoded as ISO-8859-1 when it was actually UTF-8.

But if you are talking about web page then you probably don't have ISO-8859-1, you probably have Windows code page 1252, an encoding that is similar to ISO-8859-1, but with different characters in the byte range 0x80–0x9F. If you replace `ISO-8859-1` in the code above with `windows-1252`, your example text comes out as:

```
किसानों के ल�
```

which seems closer to correct (just truncated).

In general though, trying to recover a misdecoded string is to be avoided. For many combinations of encoding a misdecoding may result in unrecoverable mangling. Much better to decode the string from its original bytes using the correct encoding in the first place. How you might do that depends on where you are getting `str` from.

Comment: I am getting str from google feed api. I made $.ajax call to google feed api and it sent me data in the success but the data has all the characters like ("à¤•à¤¿à¤¸à¤¾à¤¨à¥‹à¤‚ à¤•à¥‡ à¤²à¤). I want to convert it into hindi languages as it should be.

Comment: Hi bobince - I tried your suggestion and looks like few more hindi characters are coming up but still some garbage characters (�) are still there. Any further suggestion ?

Comment: Depending on how `str` was decoded in the first place it is possible that it may be irretrievably mangled. You need to go back and look at how `str` was gathered because the real fix should be done there.

Comment: bobince - like I said data is coming from google feed api and there is no help provided about google api resultset format.

Comment: @jasper: You should post the code you are using to read from the API.

Comment: Here is the code -
      //here is link for hindi newspaper
      var varURI = "http://www.bhaskar.com/dainikbhaskar2010/scripts/bhaskar-rss.php?cat_id=2322";

 $.ajax({
 url: "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=5&output=json&q=" + encodeURIComponent(varURI) + "&hl=hi&callback=?",
 dataType: "json",
 success: function (data) {
       //here I get response data .
 }

Comment: OK this is a bug in the Google RSS API: it is guessing a (wrong) encoding when the content-type of the feed it fetches is `text/xml` (without a `charset=`), when actually the default encoding for XML should be UTF-8. You can see this problem by browsing to http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=5&output=json&q=http://www.bhaskar.com/dainikbhaskar2010/scripts/bhaskar-rss.php?cat_id=2322 directly. Google need to fix this.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bobince for your help. :) This is a big problem, I wonder how google might have missed this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting the garbled string, you can do some changes in your tomcat's filter encoding in web.xml and connector modifications in server.xml. Below are the entries. This will change the character encoding at tomcat level, and you will get the exact characters you passed via javascript.

**web.xml**

```html
<filter> <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name> <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class> <init-param> <param-name>encoding</param-name> <param-value>UTF-8</param-value> </init-param> <init-param> <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name> <param-value>true</param-value> </init-param> </filter>
 <filter-mapping> <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name> <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> </filter-mapping>
```

server.xml

in connector tag

```html
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
.. 
..
URIEncoding="UTF-8" useBodyEncodingForURI="true" />
```